# How do I flush the DNS cache on a OS X 10.6 machine?

Tags: snow-leopard, dns

Trying to flush the local DNS cache. How is this done on Snow Leopard?

Using System Preferences and using the terminal?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use

```
sudo dscacheutil -flushcache
```

or

```
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

In 10.6 the handling of Unicast DNS is now managed by mDNSResponder - `dscacheutil -flushcache` now just tells mDNSResponder to restart (the second command above).

Comment: See [OS X: How to reset the DNS cache](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5343) from the Apple support pages.

Answer (score 9):

```
dscacheutil -flushcache
```

Comment: can it be done via pref pane?

Comment: @jdiaz No. There is no option in System Preferences to flush the DNS cache.

Comment: After I upgraded to OS X Lion, `dscacheutil -flushcache` does not seem to work anymore on my system.  Using Chealion's suggestion of sending a HUP signal to mDNSResponder does still work for me though.