# DNS not resolving on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, snow-leopard, network, dns

Some of my co-workers are having troubles on their Macs - DNS resolution does not work in Mac OS X. They're running Snow Leopard 10.6.8. They can use DNS in a Windows 7 virtual machine (VMware Fusion 3.1.3) running on OS X. The computers are 15" MacBook Pros, early 2011 model.

Things they've tried that didn't work:

- turning airport on/off
- rebooting
- using wired connection instead of wifi
- deleting connection credentials and adding it again
- turning off Mac firewall
- using static IP
- manually setting DNS servers
- restarting mDNSResponder
- the fixes from [this other question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1366/how-do-i-flush-the-dns-cache-on-a-os-x-10-6-machine)

**EDIT** response to Martín's answer:

• **Can you ping the DNS you want to use?**

```
$ ping apple.com
ping: cannot resolve apple.com: Unknown host
```

• **What is/are the IP address(es) of the DNS(s) you want to use?**

This is a company DNS server that is given with DHCP, it works well for
other people. I've also tried Google's 8.8.4.4 and 205.171.3.65 (which I found from GRC's DNS Benchmark to be the fastest).

• **Have you tried using 8.8.8.8 (google) or any of the OpenDNS
208.67.222.222 or 208.67.220.220?**

It doesn't work, see Google Chrome output:

> The server at [www.apple.com](http://www.apple.com) can't be found, because the DNS lookup failed. DNS is the network service that translates a website's name to its Internet address. This error is most often caused by having no connection to the Internet or a misconfigured network. It can also be caused by an unresponsive DNS server or a firewall preventing Google Chrome from accessing the network.

• **Can you ping those hosts?**

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes 64 bytes from
8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=0 ttl=58 time=3.925 ms
```

• **creating a blank user**

A guest user account was created, the DNS issue was still there when using
the guest account.

• **nslookup and dig both work fine**

```
$ nslookup www.apple.com 8.8.8.8
Server:  8.8.8.8
Address: 8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
www.apple.com canonical name = www.isg-apple.com.akadns.net.
www.isg-apple.com.akadns.net canonical name = www.apple.com.edgekey.net.
www.apple.com.edgekey.net canonical name = e3191.c.akamaiedge.net.
Name: e3191.c.akamaiedge.net
Address: 184.24.141.15
```

```
$ dig @8.8.8.8 www.apple.com
; <<>> DiG 9.6.0-APPLE-P2 <<>> @8.8.8.8 www.apple.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 11298
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 4, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION: ;www.apple.com.   IN A
;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.apple.com.  1041 IN CNAME www.isg-apple.com.akadns.net.
www.isg-apple.com.akadns.net. 38 IN CNAME www.apple.com.edgekey.net.
www.apple.com.edgekey.net. 8794 IN CNAME e3191.c.akamaiedge.net.
e3191.c.akamaiedge.net. 17 IN A 184.24.141.15
;; Query time: 4 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Tue Oct 4 09:25:28 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 158
```

• **also flushing the DNS cache was done but it didn't help**

```
sudo dscacheutil -flushcache
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

**EDIT 2**:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
#
# Mac OS X Notice
#
# This file is not used by the host name and address resolution
# or the DNS query routing mechanisms used by most processes on
# this Mac OS X system.
#
# This file is automatically generated.
#
domain {redacted}.com
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 208.67.222.222
```

Comment: Happens for me on lion as well.

Comment: Happening for me on Mavericks, 10.9.4

Comment: This look like an historical problem which rotted the life of users and network admins from Leopard to Yosemite. If someone still see this problem, please report clearly if you have more than one interface active and moreover getting its conf. from a DHCP server (from different sides). Why? I never saw such a problem on any other Unix and on none of my Macs (I have a lot), but none of them has more than one interface talking toward a DNS info source.

Comment: Try to change your DNS configuration (change order or remove entries), that resolve the same issue for me

Comment: I am using my own DNS server on my home network and my Mac is always forgetting the names of one local machine or another. Thank you because the following fixes it when it goes wrong:  
    `sudo dscacheutil -flushcache sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`

Answer (score 101, accepted):

It turns out the solution was to bounce mDNSResponder:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist
```

This was obtained by a different coworker from [this Server Fault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/64837/dns-name-lookup-was-ssh-not-working-after-snow-leopard-upgrade).

### OS X 10.10.0 – 10.10.3, Yosemite

[Apparently](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2015/01/why-dns-in-os-x-10-10-is-broken-and-what-you-can-do-to-fix-it/), mDNSResponder doesn't exist in Yosemite (OS X 10.10). You can restart descoveryd instead to fix these issues.

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.discoveryd.plist
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.discoveryd.plist
```

### OS X 10.10.4+, Yosemite

In OSX 10.10.4 the mDNSResponder has been [reintroduced](http://9to5mac.com/2015/05/26/apple-drops-discoveryd-in-latest-os-x-beta-following-months-of-complaints-about-network-issues-with-yosemite/). So use the first one will work again.

Comment: But this isn't really a satisfactory answer. I need to know how to stop it from happening in the first place.

Comment: My DNS (internet connection with IP addresses is fine, as is nslookup) also started going out, this brings it back without a reboot, thanks!

Comment: @dkagedal Will one of the other answers help? I'm really not familiar with networking, so this is not my forte. If you come up with a better prevention answer, please post it here!

Comment: No other answer here helps to prevent it, and I haven't found any other answer.

Comment: @dkagedal This is actually as good an answer as we're going to get - this happens because your mac caches the DNS entries to avoid hitting your DNS server (likely your router) for every DNS lookup - which happens a lot. This cache is necessary, and good, but it would be nice if there were better behavior when an entry is not found (I consider this a bug). In any case, there is some timeout in the cache; when I waited 10 minutes or so on my machine, this situation resolved itself. For the majority of users, the existing behavior is fine, so is not likely to be changed by Apple anytime soon.

Comment: Of course this is not as good as it gets. No other OS has this problem. There is nothing wrong with the DNS, the record for www.google.com didn't go missing, it's just the MacOS cache that for somehow lost it and won't refetch it. And that's a bug that needs fixing.

Comment: @dkagedal agreed it is a pretty bad bug, especially since a non-technical user can't figure out the problem, but I'm  unclear what you expect StackExchange to do about it?

Comment: Sorry, I just meant that there should be a proper answer and solution to this. And I can't imagine that everybody has this problem as it would cause enourmous amounts of grief. So there is likely something on my machine that is causing it, but I don't know what.

Comment: @dkagedal That's very probably the case. However, nobody seems to be able to diagnose the root cause. If you can come up with a better solution, I'll change my accept to it.

Comment: Got this problem on 10.9 and solution worked perfectly. In my case DNS was resolving for full names but not short ones.

Comment: Wow! you are the best! +1 :) worked like a charm!

Comment: What if that file is missing from my mac?

Comment: @Matteo Maybe the file doesn't have to exist, or maybe the answer needs to be updated for Yosemite. Do you have this issue? Does running those commands fix it?

Comment: My bad, didn't see it was related to snow-leopard, anyway no, there is nothing that can fix it other than a workaround that restart the dns daemon or the network interface every 2 mins

Comment: @Matteo You might find this article useful then - I guess mDNSResponder doesn't exist in Yosemite, though you can install it. http://arstechnica.com/apple/2015/01/why-dns-in-os-x-10-10-is-broken-and-what-you-can-do-to-fix-it/

Comment: Today I've got this frustrating problem (Yosemite 10.10.2) and the only thing that helped - was setting up Google's DNS as my primary DNS (description is here https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using) + had to edit `hosts` files for sites where I used VPN

Comment: My Yosemite is reporting that load and unload are legacy subcommands for launchctl.  What should we be doing instead?

Comment: @DavidVincent Are you using the discoveryd command? What version of Yosemite are you on? Can you post the full command and response you're using?

Comment: @CajunLuke, those are excellent questions.  I haven't tried the discoveryd command.  As I should have said in my first comment, I am on OS X Yosemite 10.10.3.  As for the command and response I'm using:  I almost tried launchctl as suggested, but decided to look first at the man page.  There's a heading for LEGACY SUBCOMMANDS that talks about load and unload.

Comment: @DavidVincent I'm not sure what replaces load and unload for launchctl, but I use those discoveryd commands whenever my network goes wonky, about once a month.

Comment: Can't reset the cache this way in Big Sur... use `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder` instead [source](https://osxdaily.com/2017/12/18/reset-dns-cache-macos-high-sierra/)

Comment: Worked on Catalina (10.15.7) after disabling System Integrity Protection https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/disabling_and_enabling_system_integrity_protection

Comment: `launchctl unload` will result in "Unload failed: 150: Operation not permitted while System Integrity Protection is engaged". `killall -HUP mDNSResponder` will solve the problem.

Answer (score 18):

Actually, I think you might want to use

```
scutil --dns

scutil -r hostname
```

These commands use the dynamic store in configd, as opposed to the flatfiles in /etc, which often are only read in single user mode and for non networked systems.

```
man scutil   # or

scutil --help
```

Comment: You don't explain why these commands would help with this problem. Do they even? Or this this meant as a comment to one of the other answers or something?

Comment: One possible advantage of scutil is that it might work regardless of whether the computer has discoveryd or mDNSResponder.  It dates from before their introduction.

Comment: these commands don't solve the issue

Comment: Thanks! This solution solved my problem. Specifically, `dig hostname` and `host hostname` was resolving the address but `ping hostname` was not resolving. After running the two commands above `ping hostname` started resolving.

Answer (score 13):

I've experienced the same problem… And while restarting mDNSResponder does seem to "work", restarting it a couple of times every hour sort of sucks.

So, for now, I've "solved" the problem by running [dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html) locally. To do that:

- Build dnsmasq (download the tgz and `make` or `brew install dnsmasq`)
- Put this in a `dnsmasq.conf` file:

  ```
  resolv-file=resolv.conf
  user=nobody
  group=nobody
  interface=lo0
  cache-size=1024
  ```
- Put this in a `resolv.conf` file that is in the same directory as the `dnsmasq.conf` file (nb: *not* `/etc/resolv.conf`):

  ```
  nameserver 8.8.8.8
  nameserver 4.2.2.1
  nameserver 4.2.2.2
  ```
- Run `dnsmasq` with `sudo dnsmasq --no-daemon --log-queries -C dnsmasq.conf`. The output should look something like:

  ```
  ...
  dnsmasq: reading resolv.conf
  dnsmasq: using nameserver 4.2.2.1#53
  dnsmasq: using nameserver 4.2.2.2#53
  dnsmasq: using nameserver 8.8.8.8#53
  dnsmasq: read /etc/hosts - 6 addresses
  ```
- Open Network Preferences and make sure that `127.0.0.1` is the only DNS server (network preferences -> advanced -> DNS -> add 127.0.0.1)

Things should begin to work nicely again.

Once things are working, you can run `dnsmasq` without the `--no-daemon` and `--log-queries` options, so it will start in the background and you don't need to keep a Terminal window open.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that after 16 straight hours scouring the Internet, this is the *only* solution I've found that both lets me resolve internal company names AND allows for split networking to function properly. Thank you SO much for making this comment.

Comment: I'd also point out that on OS X El Capitan, in order to script setting this up, I wrapped my `openconnect` command in a python script, along with commands such as `networksetup -setdnsservers 127.0.0.1` and `networksetup -setsearchdomains "$COMPANY_NAME".com`. Add in your `dnsmasq` command and it's all set! I finally have a stable VPN solution thanks to this comment.

Comment: For future readers, I found it easiest to just ssh into my box at work, determine which IP's it had for name servers, and then hardcode those IP's into my resolv.conf below 8.8.8.8 (googles DNS server). That allows all non company names to resolve properly without having to go through company servers, which I find useful for privacy and speed. As far as hardcoding goes, those IP's aren't going to change any time soon, and if they do, I won't be the only one affected and it should be trivial to edit two lines.

Comment: It says that address 127.0.0.1 is already in use, when I try to start dnsmasq. What do I have to do? High Sierra

Comment: @IceFire I know this is old but that means that there's already a service bound on that port (53). Technically that means it's getting the error *EADDRINUSE* but I won't go there :) As for this answer I find it intriguing. I have a similar problem but I think (hope) for me that the other answer will resolve it only that I don't need to enable it at least for my home network as I have my own authoritative DNS servers (and one happens to be local and what I use). Otoh as a long time Unix user the fact I could use */etc/resolv.conf* is appealing but will try the other first.

Answer (score 8):

Name resolution under OSX (and UNIX in general) is taken from the IP addresses of the DNSs in the file located in /etc/resolv.conf (which OS X automatically generates as far as I can remember).

Since you've tried virtually anything that comes to my mind, I'd like to ask you:

- Can you ping the DNS you want to use?
- What is/are the IP address(es) of the DNS(s) you want to use?
- Have you tried using 8.8.8.8 (google) or any of the OpenDNS 208.67.222.222 or 208.67.220.220?
- Can you ping those hosts?

Finally, a usually nice test consists of creating a blank user and seeing if that new user exhibits the same problem. If it doesn't, then you can start digging what your current user has that could be causing the issue; if it also fails, then you know this is something more "system" related.

Also take a look around the Console to see if you can spot something that may be related (and would like to paste around here).

Last but not least, your Mac comes with two important DNS commands, `nslookup` and `dig`.

So to resolve www.apple.com using google's server, you'd type:

nslookup "host to resolve" "DNS server to use". E.g.:

```
$ nslookup www.apple.com 8.8.8.8
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
www.apple.com   canonical name = www.isg-apple.com.akadns.net.
www.isg-apple.com.akadns.net    canonical name = www.apple.com.edgekey.net.
www.apple.com.edgekey.net   canonical name = e3191.c.akamaiedge.net.
Name:   e3191.c.akamaiedge.net
Address: 184.24.141.15
```

NSLookup is an old command (that was supposed to be deprecated some years ago and replaced by DIG, but its easy to use syntax was too good to kill I guess.), its "replacement" is `dig`, a much more powerful command, whose syntax is more crazy.

To perform the same query, you'd type:

dig @8.8.8.8 www.apple.com

ANd here's the output:

```
$ dig @8.8.8.8 www.apple.com

; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> @8.8.8.8 www.apple.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 17356
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 4, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.apple.com.         IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.apple.com.      1782    IN  CNAME   www.isg-apple.com.akadns.net.
www.isg-apple.com.akadns.net. 42 IN CNAME   www.apple.com.edgekey.net.
www.apple.com.edgekey.net. 21581 IN CNAME   e3191.c.akamaiedge.net.
e3191.c.akamaiedge.net. 2   IN  A   184.24.141.15

;; Query time: 26 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Mon Oct  3 21:21:49 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 158
```

As you can see, dig is much more "verbose" (which is good to debug what the heck is going on).
The power of dig comes from the fact that you can specify what type of query you want to perform (Among other things).

In any case, let us know the exact outputs of these commands.

Comment: See my edit to the question.

Comment: @CajunLuke hmmmm interesting… I mind adding the output of: cat /etc/resolv.conf to your question?

Comment: Edited. (Padding to make comment fit.)

Comment: @CajunLuke i'm puzzled. Let's go back to the roots… this only happens on this machine, and only under OSX, the VMs are ok. I'm starting to suspect that Parallels or VMware may be causing some trouble. What type of network are these VMs using? Bridged? Shared?

Comment: It's VMware Fusion, and we're using the NAT option. There are probably twenty identical (imaged) machines, out of which two have this issue. OS X has the problem, VMs do not.

Comment: @CajunLuke I really can't think of anything else from here. Given the reputation of both VMware and Parallels to "add stuff" to the network stack/layer and add virtual adapters, etc., I'd try completely removing VMware from the machine to see if that fixes it, which would then point you to VMware for more info. You can tell them, hey, i've got two identical machines, one works, one doesn't. Did you spot anything interesting in the Console (Applications/Utilities/Console.app) related to DNS or VMware while the resolution is in progress?

Comment: Nothing interesting in Console. Also, one of the computers having the issue spontaneously un-broke itself yesterday. We're hoping the other will, too.

Comment: Yes.. But even with my local (authoritative in fact with multi views) - as in local network - DNS server I have this problem every so often. The cache issue seems much more likely - esp since after a short while it is okay again. And just as an aside nslookup is considered obsolete or broken and has been for many many years - dig is much preferred. Also while I’m at it it's shorter to do *dig a apple.com @8.8.8.8* (or whatever your DNS server is). You don't need the CNAME stuff as long as the address record can be found (CNAME is an alias mechanism). Just fwiw.

Comment: Or if you want really short you can always do ... *dig +short a apple.com* ...

Answer (score 6):

I had the same exact same symptoms (and spend a while troubleshooting) but I was able to resolve it when I realized that I messed with `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist` and what I did was somehow interpreted as malformed. I restored from a backup and the machine was able resolve hostnames again.

Before coming to the solution, I also realized that I was able to browse the internet if I used a SOCKS5 proxy through `ssh -D` and tried DNS lookups through the tunnel.

Comment: My company has been having this issue for months and months, each time taking Macs to the "Genius bar" whose only solution was to wipe the hard drives and start over. I saw your post, and deleted com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist, rebooted, and the problem was solved. I wish I could upvote you a billion times.

Comment: Do note delete `com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist`! I did it as @TomThorogood suggested.

I have hard time to get back. Even I put the file back and restart I was unable to get any response from Internet. The `sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist` than helped.

Answer (score 5):

I had a very, very similar issue, except the symptoms were slightly different.

My user could not resolve any name (local NAS, Google etc) but a guest user on the same iMac (OS X 10.7.4) worked fine.

Flushing and restarting mDNSResponder as mentioned worked for a while. Whilst it would remain working when the iMac was put in sleep mode, it would *always* fail once rebooted.

When the flush/restart stopped working I looked for other reasons/solutions and I found that it was related to my firewall. I don't know ***what*** in my (OS X) firewall settings was causing it, but if I restored the firewall setting it worked.

To restore the default settings I used:

```
sudo cp /usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/com.apple.alf.plist /Library/Preferences/com.apple.alf.plist
```

Obviously any custom rules will have been removed with this restore.

I wanted to share my version of this issue as it's been causing me grief on and off for months and this post is the best collection of possible solutions on the net!

Answer (score 4):

I hit this problem on Yosemite (10.10).  Turns out that a key daemon, `discoveryd`, was killed off as it was consuming too much CPU.

```
2014/10/22 3:50:07.000 PM kernel[0]: process discoveryd[49] thread 1251 caught burning CPU! It used more than 50% CPU (Actual recent usage: 68%) over 180 seconds. thread lifetime cpu usage 90.016372 seconds, (74.516637 user, 15.499735 system) ledger info: balance: 90007570271 credit: 90007570271 debit: 0 limit: 90000000000 (50%) period: 180000000000 time since last refill (ns): 131905306167
```

Strangely rebooting didn't cause it to be restarted.

I manually restarted the service with:

```
sudo launchctl kickstart -k system/com.apple.networking.discoveryd
```

and now all is well.

Comment: This was the solution for me on Yosemite as well.  Some details: host, dig, and Chrome worked fine, but ping, telnet, ssh, firefox, and safari could not resolve hostnames.  This solution fixed my issue.

Comment: Annoying this happens all the time for me. Have to restart the service.

Answer (score 3):

Turning Wi-Fi off and on again helped.

<sup>MacBook Pro with 10.9.1</sup>

Especially if you turn off wifi and then reboot. The extra delay and starting with no IP/network connection ensure the request to rejoin the network has better chances to succeed.

Comment: Although the question may need some editing, it still says (at the time of writing this comment) that the workers already tried turning Wi-Fi off and on again.   Maybe we could retract this answer?

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to add a comment to a post on turning wifi off and then on, but that worked for me. Retracting the answer would be silly.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion to try again. Multiple answers help lots of people, and each router has different time outs and behaviors.

Answer (score 3):

I had seemingly the same problem as the OP.
Using the tool networksetup I found that for the given network name, some wrong DNS was configured:

```
networksetup -getdnsservers <networkname>
```

listed 192.168.0.1 as DNS. Using scutil --dns I've got comparable results, listing that resolver #2 used nameserver[0] : 192.168.0.1.

Using the command

```
networksetup -setdnsservers <networkname> 192.168.188.1 8.8.8.8
```

I was able to reconfigure the DNS for the given network and resolve names of local and global machines when connected to the VPN.

Comment: I didn't realise my MacBook had gained a wired network adaptor when I plugged it into my screen (... via a dock :facepalm:). The Wi-Fi settings were fine, but the wired network settings were _not_, and the wired network had precedence.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, everything else was fine: mDNSResponder was running and working, `host`/`nslookup` worked, both `/etc/resolv.conf` and `networksetup` reported the correct DNS servers, etc. Despite all that, DNS resolution in general (e.g. with `ping`) inevitably stopped working at some point a few hours after boot.

This specific problem may be somewhat unlikely, but I'm going to document it here as an answer anyway.

I only noticed when the machine started slowing down, but there were **a lot of identical processes running**. `sensu-client`, specifically.

We had it configured in launchd with this plist file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC -//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd>
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
  <key>KeepAlive</key>
  <true/>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
  <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
  <string>/etc/sensu</string>
  <key>UserName</key>
  <string>root</string>
  <key>Label</key><string>org.sensuapp.sensu-client</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/usr/bin/sensu-client</string>
      <string>-d/etc/sensu/conf.d/</string>
      <string>-b</string>
    </array>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

The `-b` flag to `sensu-client` makes it fork to the background, acting as a daemon. However, all `launchd` sees is that the original process terminated, so (in accordance with the `KeepAlive` flag) it restarts it. This leaves thousands of forked processes in the background, and even then launchd will be none the wiser to the fact that it is running.

I believe that these **several thousand processes** (all `sensu-client`, the software we had written a launchd config for) may have been simultaneously making requests to mDNSResponder, effectively resulting in a **local denial of service of the DNS cache**. Killing these processes and fixing the plist given to launchd eventually solved the problem.

The plist fix was just to remove the `-b` (background / daemonise) flag from the sensu-client invocation. Note that this is not sensu's fault; this plist was written by a former system administrator at this company.

Answer (score 2):

I am having the same problem with 10.6.8. The first trip to an Apple Store resulted in system restore. But, after that, DNS broke again while I was overseas and didn't have a system DVD with me. At that time I found this thread and deleted `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist` per @freezedpeanuts and @Tom Thorogood.

It fixed the problem, but, amazingly, DNS broke for the third time couple of days later. I hunted down a system image of 10.6.3 and:

1. Copied `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist` from the system image.
2. `sudo chown root /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNS*`
3. Rebooted

That fixed the problem.

It breaks periodically for me now (once a month or so), and the restore procedure is down to the steps above, except instead of rebooting you can:

`sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist`

Answer (score 2):

Please note to anyone still having issues, you might have to remove any public DNS servers until cache is cleared.

Comment: Maybe we should mention https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT203244.

Comment: @DAVincent A few years late, but that link is disappointing. It's clearly an Apple bug but they're attributing it to user error.

Answer (score 2):

This probably won't help anybody, but in case, I accidentally some time ago, created a file in the folder, when a DNS was down for a particular domain:

/etc/resolver/

and this was preventing a specific name from ever being resolved, two years later.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was my issue. I've been debugging for hours, and when I looked in /etc/resolver I of course found a file called "test", with the erronous IPs...

Comment: Exactly my issue. I only realised this once I ran `scutil --dns` and noticed that resolver #8 added custom nameservers for my problematic domain. I first tried to remove them via the `scutil` command line interface but no luck. And then I somehow stumbled upon `/etc/resolver`... hallelujah!This [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1177211) was very useful to explain the idea of DNS on macOS.

Answer (score 2):

Here are few advanced commands which can help to troubleshoot the DNS problem:

- Run `dig` to list the root name servers.
- Run `dig example.com` to run DNS lookup for `example.com` domain.
- List your hardware ports by: `networksetup -listallhardwareports`.
- Check output of the DHCP/BOOTP packet that the client accepted from the DHCP/BOOTP server by: `ipconfig getpacket en0`.
- Check your DNS configuration by: `scutil --dns`.
- Verify that `mDNSResponder` process is running by: `ps wuax | grep mDNSResponder`.
- Flush ARP translation entries by: `arp -ad` (run `man arp` for help).<sup>[source](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179362/22781)</sup>

---

To debug `mDNSResponder` process, the following command may help:

```
(sleep 1 && sudo killall -INFO mDNSResponder &); log stream | grep mDNSResponder
```

The above command will send `SIGINFO` signal to the process which will dump debugging details into log output which can be read and analysed.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately none of this helped me, and turned out after an hour of trying to figure it out and beating my head against the coffee table .. something, somehow, somewhere ... removed the `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist` file, and was the reason I had this problem.

Realized this when I saw this error message:
`/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist: No such file or directory`

Here's a copy of a version from El Capitan:
https://gist.github.com/tripflex/e7147690d1768dc74b1dd626614573c0

Here's the code from that gist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.apple.mDNSResponder.reloaded</string>
    <key>OnDemand</key>
    <false/>
    <key>InitGroups</key>
    <false/>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>_mdnsresponder</string>
    <key>GroupName</key>
    <string>_mdnsresponder</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/sbin/mDNSResponder</string>
    </array>
    <key>MachServices</key>
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.mDNSResponder</key>
        <true/>
            <key>com.apple.mDNSResponder.dnsproxy</key>
            <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>Sockets</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Listeners</key>
        <dict>
            <key>SockFamily</key>
            <string>Unix</string>
            <key>SockPathName</key>
            <string>/var/run/mDNSResponder</string>
            <key>SockPathMode</key>
            <integer>438</integer>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>POSIXSpawnType</key>
    <string>Interactive</string>
    <key>EnablePressuredExit</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings -> Network -> Advanced -> DNS. Then make literally any changes at all to DNS (reorder your DNS entries, for example). Then click "Ok" followed by "Apply" on the next screen. Don't be fooled into thinking that the particular change you made was significant; it's the magic of the "Apply" button.

```
~ $  time nslookup www.google.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached


real    0m21.041s
user    0m0.006s
sys     0m0.010s

 ~ $  time nslookup www.google.com
Server:         8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 172.217.5.4


real    0m0.079s
user    0m0.006s
sys     0m0.010s
```

Comment: I'd forgotten about this solution, and I went back and forth to various unsuccessful outcomes with most of the other solutions mentioned here. And this solution is straightforward and much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

**Restarting DNSResponder / clearing DNS cache in macOS Mojave:**

```
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

No problems with System Integrity Protection, unlike with reloading the config files.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the root cause was that the DoS protection system of my home WiFi router erroneously added the MAC address of my macOS device to the blacklist. After manually clearing the blacklist and running `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`, dig, ping and traceroute commands are all working well.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OS Mojave 10.14.6, I recently started seeing frequent dns lookup failures. I have this function in my .bashrc:

```
function resetdns() {
     dscacheutil -flushcache;
     sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
     sudo killall -9 mDNSResponder mDNSResponderHelper
     sudo launchctl stop homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq 
     sudo launchctl start homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq
}
```

On running

```
$ resetdns
```

dns lookups started working fine again.

Answer (score 1):

2022 and having this issue.

nslookup & dig returned the correct dns values but ping and ssh to the intended device just returned the public ip of my domain.

in my case I had to turn off my DNS profile and "the limit IP address tracking" in the network settings pref pane.

now everything works correctly & search domains work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Recent macOS versions which has **Private Relay** capability (Monterey and above) is schizophrenic when it comes to network access.

All the answers and tips relating to Unix/Linux network CLI tools cannot be utilized as is, since it assumes that DNS resolution is based on /etc/resolv.conf and well known tools such as *nslookup* and *host*.

On macOS with **Private Relay** enabled, the CLI tools will return the expected answers, while Applications can potentially receive a different answer when performing hostname resolution. This impacts organizations which utilize split DNS servers (hostname resolves to internal/local IPv4 address within the network). Even *scutil* could not diagnose the problem since it shows problematic hosts as *Reachable* without exposing the IP addresses used.

To overcome this issue, under the Network Preference Pane, "Limit IP Address Tracking" must be disabled. This allows for the continued use of "Private Relay" for other networks, while disabling it for networks that experience such problems.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, to solve the problem you have to configure a search domain and add it to the search domain field under System Preferences dns configuration.  Basically, the search domain will work sort of the way that .local does, but instead it will be .

You have to set up your search domain as a master zone in your dns server for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I've a similar problem with finding the host server. We have 21 iMacs running from the Server (El Capitan, recently upgraded) and only one won't bind. The fix is usually pretty simple through Users and Groups in SysPref. Deleting the host server and re-binding, finding the available server in the dropdown option, but for some unknown reason the server is listed as `unkown-00-00-12-34-56-78.home`, which I've found is the MAC address of the server.
I ran this in terminal:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist
```

and

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist
```

returned to bind to the server in SysPref and the correct server name option briefly appeared and then changed back to "unkown-00-00-12-34-56-78.home" right in front of my eyes!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had OpenDNS installed in the past and it wasn't removed cleanly. There were several dns related processes running such as DNSdnscrypt-proxy. I couldn't force quit them in Activity Monitor but I was able to stop them from starting up on restart by removing the .plist file in Library/LaunchDaemons.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was removing all the server entries from DNS Servers and Search Domains from:

System Preferences → Network → Advanced... → DNS

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling the Umbrella Roaming Client made DNS lookups work fine for me on Mac OS Mojave.

Run the application in

```
Applications > OpenDNS Roaming Client  > Umbrella Roaming Client Uninstaller.
```

Answer (score 0):

Running on MacOS Mojave 10.14.6.  Mostly the same issues, as OP & others.
Everything working fine then all of a sudden no access to Internet or Local addresses.  I can access by IP Address but not by DNS.  Neither Wifi or Wired connection. Clearly a DNS issue. I can see correct DNS entries in Network Preferences...Advanced...DNS. Up to now only resolution was a reboot. Would then work fine for a few days, then it would happen again.

What worked for me was provided above by @user674669

```
function resetdns() {
 dscacheutil -flushcache;
 sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
 sudo killall -9 mDNSResponder mDNSResponderHelper
 sudo launchctl stop homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq 
 sudo launchctl start homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq
```

}

On running

$ resetdns

I ran each line in the function individually. Will now see if I can script it, as I am pretty sure I will need it again.

So Ok, I have a resolution, but the main question is why is this happening?
Previously, I had tried "sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder" to no avail, but I had not run the other commands. I may try just the first three and see if that resolves it.  If it requires the two commands that reference homebrew, could homebrew be the problem?

I am sure I will have another opportunity to check this further.

Again many thanks to @user674669!

Update 08-26-2021:

Issue re-occurred.
Ran the first three commands only:

```
 dscacheutil -flushcache;
 sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
 sudo killall -9 mDNSResponder mDNSResponderHelper
```

...tested connection after each one.
Seemed to require all three, doesn't completely resolve the issue, only restores DNS functionality until it re-occurs.
The real issue still remains...why is this happening.

And sorry, I may be a newbie here, but I am also an analyst and have been for years. I believe my answers as posted are relevant to this topic. No one here has come up with a definite conclusive resolution to this issue. And I reference a different (but also same) answer in respect to the person (@user674669) who did provide the steps I was able to use to help partially (as the issue returns at a later time) resolve the issue. And with this update, I have determined that not all the steps posted by @user674669 are required (at least in my case) to restore the DNS functionality. I believe my comments are helpful to others having this same issue.

LThibx

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Thanks for your answer but it's a bit confusing to read because you reference a different answer.  Please [edit] your answer to only include the relevant steps to resolve the problem.  - From Review

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) Thank you for your post, I'm sure this will be helpful to others. However, you may want to edit it to remove the bits that don't belong in an *answer*. More specifically, everything from *"So, ok, I have a resolution..."* onwards could be removed, as it reads more like a question. Also, feel free to edit your answer if/when you feel you can improve/clarify it. Thanks again for your contribution! :)

Comment: This answer seems to be a mix of a (self confessed) re-iteration of [user674669'a answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/406890/100490) and a new question. There doesn't seem to be any new solution provided.

Answer (score -1):

After upgrading from Snow Leopard on an old Mac Book to Mountain Lion, the system could not resolve DNS. Flushing, restart, nothing helped. Changing WiFi to a different Access point (my phone) helped.

Mountain Lion adds a new client field to the DHCP network settings. Filling in this field seemed to make the wifi access point happy. Leaving it blank meant nothing was getting thru, even though the wifi connection seemed to succeed.