# Trying to run apache server on Mavericks

Tags: apache, web-sharing

I am trying to set up an Apache vhost on Mavericks, something that I was able to do easily on 10.6.8. I am using the default Apache that is preinstalled on a fresh install of OS X 10.9.2

```
$ sudo apachectl start
org.apache.httpd: Already loaded

$ ping localhost
PING localhost (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.053 ms
```

But when I navigate to either `http://localhost` or `http://127.0.0.1` on any of my 3 browsers, I'm told I can't connect, instead of seeing Apache's "It Works!" message. (On Chrome I see "Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost")

I also tried adding a vhost:

1. Uncommented `Include /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` in /private/var/appache2/httpd.conf
2. Added `127.0.0.1 test.local` to /etc/hosts
3. Added the following to /etc/apache2/extra/http2-vhosts.conf

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.local
    DocumentRoot /Users/me/test
    <Directory /Users/me/test>
      AllowOverride all
      Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
4. Restarted Apache

   ```
   $ apachectl -t
   Syntax OK
   $ sudo apachectl graceful
   $ ping test.local
   PING test.local (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
   64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.040 ms
   ```

...but again, nothing when I navigate to http://test.local

Any thoughts? Does this have something to do with Mavericks' new "Web Sharing" preference, which you have to download separately, or something?

---

Edit:

Figured it out! I had to modify the main httpd.conf Directory options to `AllowOverride All` and `Allow from All`, as per [this](http://classpattern.com/create-virtual-hosts-using-apache-in-mavericks.html#.U1AFheZdWJQ) tutorial. The conf file that comes with Mavericks has this turned off. If I had looked at my original conf file on my old machine, I would have noticed the difference.

The other thing that was messing me up is that if I have

```
ErrorLog "/Users/me/error.log"
```

in my VirtualHost definition, I get "Chrome can't connect", even though Apache tells me the syntax is fine. Removing it resolves the problem.

Thanks all!

Comment: You have to pay for web sharing?

Comment: As far as I understood, there is some new front-end to the server preferences that Apple wants you to pay for, but which you can avoid by modifying pref files directly. I may be mistaken on that, and I don't know if it relates to my question. In my "Sharing" folder, I don't see "Web Sharing" at all, whereas it used to be there in my 10.6.8

Comment: no there is nothing you need to pay for except you want OS X Server. But even OS X Server does not make use of the pre-installed apache. You can download a custom preference pane on the web for free here : http://clickontyler.com/web-sharing/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `/var/log/apache2/error_log` or `/var/log/system.log`. You can also try to flush the DNS cache by running `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`. See http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5343.

Just running `sudo apachectl start` makes `http://localhost` show the "It works!" page for me in a 10.9 VM.

Saving

```
<Directory "/Users/username/Sites/">
  Options Indexes Multiviews
  AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

as `/etc/apache2/users/username.conf` and running `sudo apachectl restart` makes `http://localhost/~username/` point to `~/Sites/`.

Uncommenting `Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`, adding `127.0.0.1 test.dev` to `/etc/hosts`, adding

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/Users/username/Sites/test"
  ServerName test.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

to `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`, and running `sudo apachectl restart` makes `http://test.dev` point to `~/Sites/test/`.

Comment: The first block of text is what I added the the main httpd.conf file, and that worked. I'll accept this answer, since it's closest. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, did you [flush your DNS cache](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/121432/1860) after changing the hosts file?
Run `dscacheutil -flushcache` in Terminal.

Second, you can run `apachectl -S` to check your apache2 config. Correct any errors and restart apache again.

Third, check the permissions on your `/Users/me/test` directory. Chmod the permissions on that directory to `775` or even `777` to see if that helps.

Comment: 1. Ran it now. The cache was flushed (it took Chrome several seconds longer to try and resolve the site), but still says it cannot connect. 2. I get `VirtualHost configuration: wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers: *:80 is a NameVirtualHost, default server test.local (/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:29), port 80 namevhost test.local (/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:29)`. 3. chmod to 777 and it didn't help. Also, I would still expect to see the "It Works!" message at localhost even without a vhost, right?

Comment: If you had a working setup under 10.6.8 your old httpd.conf file will be save at /etc/apache2/httpd.conf.pre-update. You can compare this with the current conf file to see if there are any other settings that are different.

Comment: yes you would. By simply doing :
sudo apachectl start
and entering "localhost" in firefox I see "It works" in the Browser.. Maybe you can try to use macports and install apache2 again, copy the "clean" config if you need to.

Comment: Ok, actually if I re-comment the line `Include /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` in httpd.conf, and re-start Apache, I *now* see the "It Works!" message. Presumably this changed after the DNS cache flush. So now I just need to work out what's wrong with my vhosts file. But it should be an easier task now, thanks.

Comment: After re-reading your original post, in your vhost section above, I think the DocumentRoot needs to be enclosed with quotes.

Comment: @JMS: It didn't in my last set-up, and adding quotes now doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Figured it out! See edit above.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated to Mavericks from Snow Leopard and my apache gave me hard time right away. After banging my head for two straight nights, reading everything about configuring Apache under Mavericks and seeing no progress on it whatsoever – I've been having "It works" message for every virtual host which was previously configured with SL and at some point even that stopped working – I've found that if you swap your old httpd.conf-previous with the newly generated httpd.conf, you should comment out `LoadModule bonjour_module     libexec/apache2/mod_bonjour.so`, too. `apachectl start` (or `restart`) doesn't throw any errors, but it actually doesn't like this module at all. So comment this one line out.

I guess, the lesson is to triple-check every directive in the config. And bang your head less, too. ;/