# Cannot ping IPv4 address, but IPv6 ping works

Tags: macos, network, wifi

I have a Macbook and an Android device (Oneplus phone) on same network and the Macbook connects via USB LAN (or Wi-Fi), Android device via Wi-Fi. I detected the following anomaly:

- I can ping the Oneplus from the Mac:

```
64 bytes from 192.168.1.127: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=30.433 ms
--- 192.168.1.127 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
```

- I can ping the router from the Oneplus
- However I cannot ping the IPv4 address of the Mac
- I took a look at the traffic in Wireshark and I got the "host unreachable" message to the ICMP requests
- I also started to host a simple HTTP server, but it seems the Mac does not response to the TCP SYN segments, because I could see RTO flagged segments (Retransmission Timeout). (3-Way handshake never completed)
- Fan fact, recently my ISP started issuing IPv6 addresses and I tried to ping the Mac from the Oneplus:

```
--- 2001:*:*:*:*:*:*:7e50 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 6.737/33.397/108.664/43.467 ms
```

It was working as the above log shows.

Mac's firewall is disabled and there is no firewall rule applied in the router. I removed all network interface under the *System Preferences / Network* menu and added them again.

I also selected the *Link-local only* option at the *System Preferences / Network / interface / Advanced / TCP/IP / IPv6 Configuration* tab. Unfortunately none of them worked.

My question is why did IPv6 ping work and IPv4 not? Could be the problem the recently introduced IPv6 addresses?

**[Edit]**

I created a Hotspot with my iPhone and connected with both of the Mac and the Oneplus. This Hotspot does not have any IPv6 configuration, but I experienced the same issue.

I also created a Hotspot with my Mac to eliminate the router from the circle and I connected to it with the Oneplus. Like every time, I could not ping the Mac, despite the Oneplus gets IP address via DHCP from the Mac. (So there was network traffic)

Comment: Pinging a router can be a tricky thing.  First remember, the router has two interfaces - internal and external.  The router probably has an IPv4 to an IPv6 bridge that will translate the address for you.  So from the inside LAN , you can ping the external interface with the v6 address the ISP issued.  Going the other way, the router usually  doesn't know anything about the internal LAN because it faces a firewall.

Comment: The Checkpoint VPN Client caused the problem. Despite I removed it from the applications, the Security Policy rules still lived somehow. So I had to download the installer again, run the uninstall script and voila.

Comment: You should add this key information within your question. This is a fundamental information: another interface. You should also add how this VPN is configured for IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: Lol man, you scrawling the stackoverflow and downvote the not 100% precisely detailed or summarised questions? For your information there was no other interface, because I had already removed the VPN client, when I posted this question. I also did not have any information about the configuration and I did not want to analyse too.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and got a positive response when using IPv6 (ping6) but not IPv4 (ping). I also had the symptoms described in the question [Why will my Mac only load Google and Facebook?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/141381/why-will-my-mac-only-load-google-and-facebook).

This problem started to appear after disconnecting from the VPN. So, after terminating the VPN service, networking began to work fine again.

```
sudo killall -9 vpnagentd ciscod
```