# Domain Name Resolution (DNS) stops working randomly

Tags: network, macos, dns

While browsing and using the web, DNS stops working. Open web-chats like Google Hangouts keep working, but opening new websites, Skype, and others are stuck to "Resolving host name".

This happens randomly, sometimes when I return from sleep mode, others when I switch from WiFi to ETH, others just while doing nothing in particular.
I tried things suggested in [DNS not resolving on Mac OS X](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/26616/dns-not-resolving-on-mac-os) without any success.

Moreover, I can resolve the problem if I reboot the Mac entirely, but I want to figure out 1) why its happening and 2) how to fix it once and for all!

- I'm running 10.11.1 (15B42)
- I'm on a home network, my ISP is [Kabel Deutchland](http://de.ccm.net/faq/1431-dns-server-deutscher-internetanbieter#dns-kabel-deutschland)
- My router doesn't accept "custom" DNS servers and I can only change them in every client.
- I am using Google DNS servers since sometime while trying to solve the problem.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31078/discussion-on-question-by-george-katsanos-domain-name-resolution-dns-stops-wor).