# curl not downloading pear.phar on Mac Mojave

Tags: macos, mojave, iterm

i do try to `curl -O https://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar`

but all i got is a log raising the `time spent`:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:03:14 --:--:--     0
```

while doing `curl -O https://andrekelling.de/site/assets/files/1050/jspdf-preview.170x120.jpg`:

brings up a response immediately:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  4565  100  4565    0     0  34145      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 34067
```

---

Also every `homebrew install` just stucks on downloading. Which i hope is related to this. Some more log info's here: https://gist.github.com/AndreKelling/49fc53014e044fac706900f3d981d4ec

---

What could this be related to?
Is it something with my `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist` i would need to unload and load again?

---

**edit**

seems to be an issue with DNS

```
> curl -O http://www.aip.de/\~wasi/PI/Pibel/pibel_1mio1.ps.gz -vvv                                                                                                                                         
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 141.33.207.249...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.aip.de (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /~wasi/PI/Pibel/pibel_1mio1.ps.gz HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.aip.de
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
>
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:04 --:--:--     0^C
```

*Connected to www.aip.de (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)*

---

**edit2**

a ping to this host is looking good.

```
ping https://pear.php.net/
PING https://pear.php.net/ (62.138.238.45): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 62.138.238.45: icmp_seq=0 ttl=249 time=18.221 ms
64 bytes from 62.138.238.45: icmp_seq=1 ttl=249 time=18.204 ms
64 bytes from 62.138.238.45: icmp_seq=2 ttl=249 time=21.171 ms
64 bytes from 62.138.238.45: icmp_seq=3 ttl=249 time=21.416 ms
64 bytes from 62.138.238.45: icmp_seq=4 ttl=249 time=20.371 ms
64 bytes from 62.138.238.45: icmp_seq=5 ttl=249 time=19.612 ms
64 bytes from 62.138.238.45: icmp_seq=6 ttl=249 time=20.144 ms
^C
--- https://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 7 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 18.204/19.877/21.416/1.193 ms
```

a ping to this host looks not good.

```
ping www.aip.de
PING proxy-intra-new.aip.de (141.33.207.249): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
Request timeout for icmp_seq 4
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5
Request timeout for icmp_seq 6
Request timeout for icmp_seq 7
^C
--- proxy-intra-new.aip.de ping statistics ---
9 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
```

---

**edit 3**

```
traceroute www.aip.de
traceroute to proxy-intra-new.aip.de (141.33.207.249), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  fritz.box (192.168.178.1)  1.708 ms  2.726 ms  2.573 ms
 2  62.155.240.129 (62.155.240.129)  7.904 ms  8.724 ms  10.405 ms
 3  62.154.15.250 (62.154.15.250)  16.691 ms  17.244 ms  16.199 ms
 4  ffm-b4-link.telia.net (213.248.93.186)  21.078 ms  20.600 ms  19.526 ms
 5  ffm-bb4-link.telia.net (62.115.120.7)  17.347 ms  18.571 ms
    ffm-bb3-link.telia.net (62.115.120.1)  16.594 ms
 6  ffm-b12-link.telia.net (62.115.142.5)  16.440 ms
    ffm-b12-link.telia.net (62.115.142.47)  19.445 ms
    ffm-b12-link.telia.net (62.115.142.5)  17.542 ms
 7  dfn-ic-326948-ffm-b12.c.telia.net (213.248.97.41)  16.175 ms  16.906 ms  15.784 ms
 8  cr-han2-be6.x-win.dfn.de (188.1.144.134)  22.745 ms  21.892 ms  22.000 ms
 9  kr-apipot7.x-win.dfn.de (188.1.33.158)  24.480 ms  26.536 ms  26.872 ms
10  141.33.49.142 (141.33.49.142)  25.103 ms  25.445 ms  26.147 ms
11  * * *
12  * * *
^C
```

Comment: Does any download with `curl` fail (if yes, please update question title and content so it don't look like a problem with a specific site)? Does the problem persist after a reboot?

Comment: it does not fail for any. that google.com page curl works fine. maybe i should try another one? yes, it persist's after reboot.

Comment: In the example you show all you got back is an error document. Which may work even if downloading a lot of data fails. Try to `curl -O http://www.aip.de/~wasi/PI/Pibel/pibel_1mio1.ps.gz` for instance (about 550 kB, the first million digits of PI)

Comment: hmm.. yes, not sure. verbose output shows that requested source as localhost IP. ist that a hint?

Comment: @nohillside added another example where curl works

Comment: Agreed, seems to be an issue with your DNS setup.

Comment: OK, good to have feedback on this so far. Any idea how to proceed now? is it something related to this: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/26616/dns-not-resolving-on-mac-os-x ?

Comment: It probably doesn‘t hurt to try the steps described there, and amend the question with any findings.

Comment: Have you tried pinging the site?

Comment: @chrisdahfuh just added the ping. which is looking fine. think i gonna do unload and load again my com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist file. which i just can do when my System Integrity Protection is off. which i just can turn off when going into the macs boot recovery mode: https://www.howtogeek.com/230424/how-to-disable-system-integrity-protection-on-a-mac-and-why-you-shouldnt/

Comment: Technically you can‘t ping files, only hosts. But the name resolution seemed to work, can you ping www.aip.de as well?

Comment: @nohillside aha, ok. just changed by post and added pings to the hosts. where one is working and one not... weird.

Comment: Can you run traceroute for the second host?

Comment: @nohillside it's really a remote debugging session :) added that `traceroute`. thanks.

Comment: Well, the second one looks like a routing problem beyond your control. IP of pear.php.net is 109.203.101.62, can you try `curl -k -O https://109.203.101.62/go-pear.phar`(the `-k` prevents `curl` from stumbling over a certificate mismatch)?

Comment: hmm. doesn't work either. isn't the IP of https://pear.php 62.138.239.45? just this what my `nslookup https://pear.php` says. `nslookup 109.203.101.62` says ** server can't find 62.101.203.109.in-addr.arpa: NXDOMAIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it appears to be this issue: [DNS not resolving on Mac OS X](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/26616/dns-not-resolving-on-mac-os-x) with the help of **Disable System Integrity Protection** https://www.howtogeek.com/230424/how-to-disable-system-integrity-protection-on-a-mac-and-why-you-shouldnt/

Steps i had to do:

1. Boot into recovery mode, restart your Mac and hold Command+R as it boots. You’ll enter the recovery environment. Click the “Utilities” menu and select “Terminal” to open a terminal window.
2. `csrutil disable`
3. restart mac
4. `sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist`
5. `sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist`
6. Boot into recovery mode
7. `csrutil enable`
8. restart mac