# Mac cannot resolve DNS on WiFi, but works fine on cellular tethering

Tags: macos, network, wifi, dns, tethering

I have consulted the questions/answers [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/26616/dns-not-resolving-on-mac-os-x). But it seems nothing is working.

- I can `ping 8.8.8.8`, but I cannot `ping www.google.com`.
- `nslookup www.google.com 8.8.8.8` and `dig @8.8.8.8 www.google.com` is not working.
- I have changed the DNS to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4. It's not working too.
- I have try to locate the file `System/.../com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist`. The file is there and nothing is wrong.
- I have make sure that `/etc/resolver` has nothing (actually, the folder `resolver` isn't even there).
- My iPhone, which is connected to the same wifi, can browse the internet just fine.
- This Mac can browse from the same wifi yesterday just fine.
- When I change my Mac connection to iPhone tethering 4G, only then it works fine (then I write this question).

How can I resolve this?

Result of `scutil --dns`:

```
scutil --dns
DNS configuration

resolver #1
  nameserver[0] : 8.8.8.8
  nameserver[1] : 8.8.4.4
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000002 (Reachable)

resolver #2
  domain   : local
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300000

resolver #3
  domain   : 254.169.in-addr.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300200

resolver #4
  domain   : 8.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300400

resolver #5
  domain   : 9.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300600

resolver #6
  domain   : a.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300800

resolver #7
  domain   : b.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 301000

DNS configuration (for scoped queries)

resolver #1
  nameserver[0] : 8.8.8.8
  nameserver[1] : 8.8.4.4
  if_index : 6 (en0)
  flags    : Scoped, Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000002 (Reachable)
```

Result of `dig`:

```
dig

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>>
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Result of `dig @8.8.8.8 www.apple.com`

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> @8.8.8.8 www.apple.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Result of `nslookup www.apple.com 8.8.8.8`

```
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Result of `ping www.google.com`:

```
ping www.google.com
ping: cannot resolve www.google.com: Unknown host
```

Result of `ping 8.8.8.8`:

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=0 ttl=58 time=71.267 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=48.360 ms
```

EDIT: added requested TCP/IP screenshot of the connected problematic wifi.

[image: TCP/IP screenshot]

Comment: I can't read most of that but `254.169.in-addr.arpa` would tell me your Mac is not reaching a DHCP server & is using a self-assigned IP Address… which is not routable & therefore will not be able to resolve DNS. To eliminate all the confusion of Terminal & dig etc, just open System Prefs > Network & click on the connected  'WiFi', then Advanced > TCP/IP & add a screenshot.

Comment: @Tetsujin I have added the requested TCP/IP screenshot. Please have a look.

Comment: OK, so long as that's your actual subnet & default gateway. Some ideas… Test removing the forced DNS & let it find your default ISP one instead [it will show your gateway address greyed out when it's set to default]. Change IPv6 to Link-Local only in case of a bad 4/6/4 interface somewhere. See if 802.1x is empty & that no proxies are enabled .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people who still have this problem, the solution is actually simple.

- Open System Preferences.
- Open Network.
- Select iPhone USB.
- Make sure "Disable unless needed" is checked.

Previously, I was tinkering with network settings because I noticed that my tethering internet connection is unstable whenever I tethered to the iPhone via USB instead of actually making a network tethering connection. I thought turning off this setting would help the connection. But turns out it has a side effect like that. Once I turn this setting on again, it works like usual.

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate one more avenue of investigation, what happens if you use this laptop on a different wifi network?  A library, business, friends place etc?  If dns works on a different wifi network, consider a router issue. Tethering to iPhone would bypass your router, and then you indicated that dns works.

Edit: I assumed this was a laptop, but if it’s not a portable machine, can you test a different WiFi router in your network?

Comment: At the moment I don't have direct access to other wifi networks, as that indeed will require me to go to a public place like a restaurant or library. Will try to find something and give you an update soon.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved it as below.

- Change mac address for Wi-Fi (I use macchanger https://github.com/acrogenesis/macchanger)
- Reconnect to wifi

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to remove all custom DNS Servers in the network settings[image]