macOS keeps logging me out of Google accounts used in Mail
Yesterday I suddenly started to get the following error a couple of times per day:

I haven't made any changes to my Google account in quite a while and I don't have any similar issues outside of the Mail app which uses emails connected to an Apple account. Are there any actions that can help me? I do login using authenticator app?
I use MacOS 14.5 (23F79) with Macbook Pro M1

What Mac are you using? What OS version?

Can you log into your google account in a browser? It looks like macOS is passing on a request from Google. Apple won't reset any password that does not log into Apple servers/services.

@benwiggy I use MacOS 14.5 (23F79)

@SteveChambers indeed I am logged out from google account in Safari, but not in Chrome or Arc browsers. Are there any ways to debug/fix it?

maybe this is somehow related, but I recently had a DNS issue and found the solution here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/26616/dns-not-resolving-on-mac-os-x
I needed to do couple of times:
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist

Safari keeps credentials in the system keychain. BUT Google had me set up app-specific passwords for my Gmail account years ago. That you can log into Gmail via a browser means it is not a problem with your account, rather the issue is the authorization mail.app is using to access your gmail account. If you don't have app specific passwords in Gmail then set them up, if you do, change it. There are instructions for this in Gmail settings. Since Gmail works in a browser but intermittently in mail.app you need to look at how mail.app is authenticating.

In the end, I just deleted and readded google accounts. It didn't help me after the first time, but it started to work after the second!

@Demian I'm glad you sorted it out. Could you to rewrite your comment into an answer? That'd be a great help to others who have a similar issue. You can then accept your own answer.
