# How do I flush the DNS cache on iOS?

Tags: ios, dns

Similar question to [How do I flush the DNS cache on a OS X 10.6 machine?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1366/how-do-i-flush-the-dns-cache-on-a-os-x-10-6-machine), but for iOS in general.

Specifically, my use case is to flush the DNS cache for applications I downloaded from App Store. Likely apps with native networking implemented (example: apps that use [Foundation's NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlsession)).

Running an iPhone 7 on iOS 10.2.1 in China with frequent DNS hijacking happening before you even have time to connect to VPN, so rebooting the device would not be a sufficient solution.

Answer (score 3):

Turn on/off of the `Airplane mode` in the `Settings.app` or `Control Center` makes it fast to flush the DNS cache.

Comment: Works well for iOS 12

Answer (score 1):

I had an iPad mini that wasn't flushing DNS when I tried turning on/off Airplane mode, nor was it flushing DNS when I tried turning on/off Wifi. I had also cleared the cache and cookies, but no cigar.

What worked for me was completely rebooting the device.

Comment: Well, my question stated: "_rebooting the device would not be a sufficient solution._"

Comment: VPNs and DNS hijacking are beyond the scope of your question, though. Better suited as separate questions.